# Using Dispatcher correctly in event to update UI

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm using dispatchers to update a bound collection from an event. I just ran into a nasty issue where I had two different dispatchers in the same event and it wasn't working. Using the debugger it was completely skipping over the code in the first dispatcher. Putting the entire event in a single dispatcher fixed it. I assume it's because of how the compiler handles it, can anyone confirm this - only one dispatcher per event, at least when dealing with the same elements?

Here is the code, when it gets to the await after (line == 0), it exits the function completely. Later, when line !=0 it runs the "Old style menu" fine. If I put all of the code in a single dispatcher, everything works fine.

```
    private async void ProcessNLS(string parameters) // NET/USB List Info
    {
        if (parameters.Substring(0, 1) == "A" || (parameters.Substring(0, 1) == "U")) // ASCII x08/2010  Only
        {
            int line = Convert.ToInt32(parameters.Substring(1, 1));
            string text = parameters.Substring(3);

            // New Menu, Clear Old - Use Last Received/Holding Menu: See NLT bug
            if (line == 0)
            {
                await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    State.Menu.ServiceType = State.holdingMenu.ServiceType;
        ...
                    State.Menu.Items.Clear();
                });

                OnMenuTitleInfoChanged(new MenuTitleInfoChangedArgs(State.Menu));

                // Replace Network Top with custom menu
                if (State.Menu.LayerInfo == LayerTypes.NetworkTop)
                {
                    await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                    {
                        State.Menu.Items.Clear();
                    });

        ...
                }

                // Get 1st Advanced Menu
                if (Device.SupportsAdvancedMenus & State.Menu.LayerInfo != LayerTypes.NetworkTop)
                {
        ...
                }

            }

            // Old style menu
            if (!Device.SupportsAdvancedMenus && State.Menu.LayerInfo != LayerTypes.NetworkTop)
            {
                NetworkMenuItem menuItem = new NetworkMenuItem(line, text);

                await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    State.Menu.Items.Add(menuItem);
                });

                OnMenuLoading(new MenuLoadingArgs(menuItem));
            }
        }

        // C - Track Cursor
        if (parameters.Substring(0,1) == "C")
        {
            if (parameters.Substring(1, 1)== "-")
            {
                // No Cursor
                // Sent when entering player screen
                await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
        ...
                    State.Menu.Items.Clear();

                    OnMenuTitleInfoChanged(new MenuTitleInfoChangedArgs(State.Menu));
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

Like this it would just jump over the dispatcher for no apparent reason. If I put the entire thing in a single dispatcher it works fine.

A second question, if I have another event with a dispatcher, something like this:

```
        foreach (xxx)
        {
            if (xxx == yyy)
            {
                await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                {
                    State.Menu.Items.Add(menuItem);
                });
            }
        }
```

Would it be preferable to instead wrap the entire foreach loop in a dispatcher rather then calling it when needed each iteration?

Since my original question has changed I've made a new post with more specifics and another possible solution by just wrapping the original socket listener task in a dispatcher

[Possible solution to issue with multiple UI dispatchers in the same method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493228/possible-solution-to-issue-with-multiple-ui-dispatchers-in-the-same-method)

*** Update:

I think Raymond is on the right track, though adding Task didn't fix it, I noticed although it starts processing line "0" of the menu, before it sets up the new menu it tries to process the next line "1" command which is ignored because it doesn't have the right menu state yet, it still hasn't been set by the previous command yet.

I'm not sure how to fix it, it seems like I have to do an await at a lower level so be sure sure it full finishes one command before starting the next (and not sure why putting the whole ProcessNLS in UI dispatcher works), it's a little complicated since I go through multiple levels but here is the flow:

```
        socket = new StreamSocket();
        try
        {
            await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(HostName), Port);
            OnConnect(new EventArgs());
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(WaitForMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnConnectionFail(new EventArgs());
        }
```

Goes to:

```
private async void WaitForMessage() 
{
...

                foreach (var message in messages)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
                        continue;

                    ProcessMessage(message);
                }

}
```

Goes to

```
    private void ProcessMessage(string message, string optionalFlags = "")
    {
...
            case "NLS": // NET/USB List Info
                ProcessNLS(parameters);
                break;       
    }
```

to finally

```
 private async void ProcessNLS(string parameters) // NET/USB List Info
```

My alternate solution is to put to ProcessMessage call under WaitForMessage in a UI dispatcher

*** Update #2

I think this may be working, here is the updated flow, have to await multiple steps, use task instead of void

```
    private async void WaitForMessage()
    {
 ...
                foreach (var message in messages)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
                        continue;

                    await ProcessMessage(message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("WaitForMessage Error: " + ex.Message);
            OnDisconnect(new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```

to

```
    private async Task ProcessMessage(string message, string optionalFlags = "")
    {
        ...
           case "NLS": // NET/USB List Info
                await ProcessNLS(parameters);
                break;

        }
```

to

```
    private async Task ProcessNLS(string parameters) // NET/USB List Info
```

Comment: The main application thread I believe? The events trigger off commands coming in over the network and update the UI using the dispatcher

Comment: If I try to update the UI from an event though it will crash so maybe it is, I don't really do anything special: An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

Comment: Your first code block is just a sketch, but we need to see the details to know what's going on with the first dispatcher. My guess is that you are doing an `await Dispatcher.RunAsync(..., async () => { })` which does not do what you think. The outer `await` will complete as soon as the async lambda hits its first `await`.

Comment: I've added in the original code and linked another post where I had another possible solution

Comment: Your `await Task.Factory.StartNew(WaitForMessage);` doesn't actually wait for `WaitForMessage` to run to completion. It will complete as soon as `WaitForMessage` does its first `await`.

Comment: When I added await to ProcessMessage and ProcessNLS, changing ProcessNLS to return a task as shown in update #2 it seems to work. Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Whether this is the best way to do it depends on what you want. If you want messages to be processed in strict sequential order (so that processing a new message cannot start until processing the old message is fully complete), then you need to `await ProcessMessage()` so that the next message doesn't start processing until the previous one is done. It's also not clear what `await Task.Factory.StartNew(WaitForMessage);` is trying to accomplish. Do you want to wait until `WaitForMessage` runs to completion before exiting the function? If so, then `await StartNew` will not do what you want.

Comment: Yes, I want it to go in order, most commands it doesn't matter but some, like the menu, cause issues.  I'm correct that after await ProcessMessage, I also need to await ProcessNLS(parameters) in processmessage,. and then an async task on processnls? Seems like it should trickle down, but doesn't if I'm doing it right

Comment: Use `await` if you want the function to run to completion before continuing with the next statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
private async void ProcessNLS(...)
        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You declared an `async void` function, which means "When the first `await` happens, return from the function immediately, and let the rest of the work run asynchronously." If you want the caller to be able to await on completion of your function, change the signature to `private async Task ProcessNLS(...)`.

Comment: That didn't fix it, but I think it's on the right track and I've updated the main post

Comment: Does the caller of `ProcessNLS` do an `await`, to ensure that all the processing for line 0 is complete before it tries to process line 1?

Comment: It didn't, I had the follow listed in the original post under "update". I had to add an await to several of the levels but I think it's working (new flow under update #2 in original post) but does it look like the best way/proper way to do it?

Comment: If you don't await, then the caller will continue with the next line of code without waiting for the called function to run to completion.